# react native drawer navigation drag drawer from left to right didn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have problem with drawer navigation. I can't drag the drawer from left to right and when I open the drawer from the button I can't press outside the drawer to close it.

It works with `expo` but not with `react-native init`.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions: {
                drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',

                drawerIcon: (
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                        source={require('./assets/IconDrawerNavigation/home.png')}
                    />
                ),
            },
        },
        AboutUs: {
            screen: AboutUs,
            navigationOptions: {
                drawerIcon: (
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                        source={require('./assets/IconDrawerNavigation/about-us.png')}
                    />
                ),
            },
        },
        Logout: {
            screen: HomePage,
            navigationOptions: {
                drawerIcon: (
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
                        source={require('./assets/IconDrawerNavigation/logout.png')}
                    />
                ),
            },
        },
    },
    {
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
        contentOptions: {
            // activeBackgroundColor: 'red',

            labelStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'SomeFont',
                color: 'white',
            },
        },
    }
);
```

Comment: This helped me (https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you installed and linked `react-native-gesture-handler` correctly. You can find how to install it [here](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#installation) (There are a few more steps on android. Make sure you do it carefully). Also in `navigationOptions` of `Home`, `drawerLockMode` is set to `locked-closed` which means you can't use gestures to open or close the drawer. From [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode) you should set it to `unlocked`.